# JQuery/Javascript popup dismiss before download on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file that can be downloaded onto mobile phones on my mobile website. Now the file can be downloaded by simply clicking on an anchor tag. Now I want to display a javascript popupbox with some important info before the download is started, and before you can initiate the download, you must dismiss the popup box(by just clicking agree/ok...) or just by clicking on another 'Download Now' button. how do I do that?

My attempt: As you can see in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccrAF/26/), I'm not sure how to initiate the file download once clicking on the 'Download Now' button.

I think plain javascript might be better since I'm not sure including a jquery file into a mobile site is always the best thing, especially for mobiles with slow internet connections...but jquery will also do for now
Thank You

Comment: Dont forget about a pound sign if myClass is an ID: $('#myClass') instead of $('myClass')

Comment: yeah thanks, spotted that as well...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following jquery: 
@bingjie: Which one do you think will be better? Mine or yours?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#dialog-download ").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    width: 325,
    modal: true
});
    $(".opener").click(function(){
        var that = this;

        $("#dialog-download").dialog("option",  {buttons: {
            "Download Now": function(){
             $("a").attr("href", "http://dl.v4m.mobi/bb/2012_07_10/OS-v5.0up/e_phone.jad");  
             window.location.href = $('#myClass').attr('href');

            }
        }
            });
        $("#dialog-download").dialog("open");
    });
});
```